# xmlstarlet count comma separated

Tags: xmlstarlet

In need a count of the cluster-address (number of servers), see xml below. Can anyone help me. I tried so many things but i can't get it to work.

The servers in the cluster-address are separated by a comma.

```
<name>WeblogicCluster</name>
<multicast-address>1.1.1.1.1</multicast-address>
<cluster-messaging-mode>unicast</cluster-messaging-mode>
<cluster-address>server1.domain.com,server2.domain.com</cluster-address>
<weblogic-plugin-enabled>true</weblogic-plugin-enabled>
<frontend-host>server.domain.com</frontend-host>
```

In bash i solved it like this, however is was hoping to do this in xmlstarlet, any ideas?

```
#!/bin/sh
address="$(xmlstarlet sel -N d=http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain -t -v "/d:domain/d:cluster/d:cluster-address" config.xml 2>/dev/null)"
number=`echo ${address//","/" "} | wc -w`
echo $number
```

Comment: #!/bin/sh
address="$(xmlstarlet sel -N d=http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain -t -v "/d:domain/d:cluster/d:cluster-address" config.xml 2>/dev/null)"
number=`echo $address | awk -F "," '{ for (i=1; i<NF; i++) printf $i"\n" ; print $NF }' | wc -w`
echo $number

Answer (score 0):

`xml sel -N d=http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain -t -v \
 "count(str:split(/d:domain/d:cluster/d:cluster-address, ','))" \
 config.xml`